# Objective C Domain Driven Design

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller, model, domain-driven-design

Normally when programming in C# I architect my project after the domain driven principles.  I am new to programming in Objective C for iPhone and was wondering if anyone had any sample projects or code that uses the domain driven design principles in Objective C.  I am looking for examples of how Business Objects, etc are used.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a chance that you misunderstand what Domain Driven Design principles are. DDD is a set of guidelines, it is more about how you think and how you approach problems, it is mostly technology agnostic. Nothing prevents your design from being driven by domain instead of technology if you write Objective C code (I personally liked the fact that you have to name arguments because it made for a more readable code in my opinion).

Your question is probably about technologies that usually support (but not define) DDD: ORM, DI, Unit Tests. And this part is not so good IMHO (based on short and relatively outdated experience). Instead of using ORM you usually employ [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html) which is an object graph persister that is suppose to be even better in theory because you don't deal with 'Relational' part. I remember however that Core Data put certain restrictions on my object model that I would wanted to avoid in other environments. Can not speak for DI, but unit testing was a pain (in 2010) and I've heard it still is in 2012.

The bottom line is that you would have to elaborate on your question, split it and maybe ask it in Objective-C section.

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised that no one mentioned how anti DDD CoreData is. Even with CRUD style apps, I always try to code DDD style. One of the first things you will notice is the extensive use of CoreData throughout Cocoa, specially on Mac.

XCode and Cocoa promotes the use of CoreData along bindings. However CoreData forces you all the time coding to the database, not the domain model. Indeed, you cannot rename a single domain object attribute without forcing a whole database migration.

If you are learning Cocoa you will have to learn CoreData because many apps and sample code rely on it. Later on, as your knowledge of the framework matures, you might want to drop CoreData altogether if you really want a domain model, which is what I usually do for my own projects.

Comment: I think this is a problem, too. Using a 'managed' model and create domain objects from it (domain model object `Movie` is created by a Core Data-backed repository which fetches `ManagedMovie` and copies the attributes) is just too cumbersome. The Core Data stuff is part of infrastructure and leaves no room in the domain itself. How do you solve that exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I came from a C# background as well and after half a year of getting into ObjC I must say that it is certainly possible to follow the DDD principles fully in Objective-C. Partly because of the static/dynamic hybrid smalltalk-ish nature of the language.

For example, you can 'hijack' message sent to objects (aka intercepting method calls) very easily just by overriding a few methods which makes DI and Unit Testing very easy to do if you understand what I mean.

Additionally, the [grand central dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) makes for a very nice decoupled message sending across systems which you can use to ease communication between big parts of your domain.

Finally, the [key-value observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) convention in the base framework allows you to easily connects your domain objects to user interface elements and have changes reflected in real-time.

i.e. instead of manipulating service objects directly, your controllers would instead send commands to one of your domain objects to which would modify its state. Those states are then easily reflected back by making your controller observe the changes (via the KVO mechanism.)

So I'd say it's totally possible/even easier in ObjC to follow the DDD principle.

As for examples, I have never seen any. But it certainly is not hard to follow the same structure you use in C# projects (not copy them, but model it similarly). Studying the technologies I mentioned will helps you a lot as well.